# How to use copy() function and paste file in /wp-content/themes directory

Tags: php, plugin-development, theme-development

```
copy("http://localhost/medium/theme.zip","themenew.zip");
```

currently it is pasting file in wp-admin folder, Is there any way I can copy .zip file to /wp-content/themes directory.

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution:

```
copy("http://localhost/medium/theme.zip", get_theme_root() . "/themenew.zip");
```