# Right way to download file from source to destination

Tags: uploads, filesystem, wp-filesystem, filesystem-api

I'm trying to download a file from one location to another. The code is working perfect. Here is the code snippet:

**Helper Function** - Create directory in `/uploads/{$dir_name}/` and return paths.

```
/**
 * Create folder in /uploads/{$dir_name}/
 * @return array()
 */
function get_dirpath( $dir_name = 'test' ) {
    
    $wp_info  = wp_upload_dir();

    // SSL workaround.
    if ( is_ssl() ) {
        $wp_info['baseurl'] = str_ireplace( 'http://', 'https://', $wp_info['baseurl'] );
    }

    // Build the paths.
    $dir_info = array(
        'path'   => $wp_info['basedir'] . '/' . $dir_name . '/',
        'url'    => $wp_info['baseurl'] . '/' . $dir_name . '/'
    );

    // Create the upload dir if it doesn't exist.
    if ( ! file_exists( $dir_info['path'] ) ) {

        // Create the directory.
        mkdir( $dir_info['path'] );

        // Add an index file for security.
        file_put_contents( $dir_info['path'] . 'index.html', '' );
    }

    return $dir_info;
}
```

**Way - 1** - Using PHP `copy()` function - *{works perfect}*.

```
$dir_info    = get_dirpath( 'test' );
$remote_file = 'https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
$local_file  = trailingslashit( $dir_info['path'] ) . basename( $remote_file );

if ( copy( $remote_file, $local_file ) ) {
    //  Successfully copy file from URL
}
```

**Way - 2** - Using WordPress `WP_Filesystem_Direct` - *{works perfect}*

```
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php';
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php';
$my_filesystem = new WP_Filesystem_Direct( array() );

if ( $my_filesystem->copy( $remote_file, $local_file, true) ) {
    //  Successfully copy file from URL
}
```

> Both, Works perfect.

This code snippet:

- Create the file `googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png`
- In directory `/wp-content/uploads/test/`
- From source `https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png`

---

I think, I need to use `Way - 2`. But, Is this right way to `include files` and create `new WP_Filesystem_Direct()` object?

I search little bit regarding and found
[Copy a file from a plugin into my theme directory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145254/copy-a-file-from-a-plugin-into-my-theme-directory)
and
[How to use copy() function and paste file in /wp-content/themes directory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215609/how-to-use-copy-function-and-paste-file-in-wp-content-themes-directory)

But, Not found any solution / snippet which use the `Way - 2`.

**Edited:** - The `global $wp_filesystem` does same thing from `way - 2`. But, Its not working ( Don't know why! ).

---

#### Updated

Also, How to get valid error message if it fail the file download?

Comment: if it does the job I'm not sure what the problem is, every snippet or tutorial had to be written once the first time, perhaps this is your opportunity!

Comment: Yes it works. But, `global $wp_filesystem`do same thing like 2nd way. I tried to use this `global $wp_filesystem;` in hooks `init`, `admin_init` But, This global variable does not works ( I don't know why ). Just want to know the valid way

Comment: Ah after reading Marks answer I spotted that you're not copying files at all, you're doing a download of a remote file! I've updated your question accordingly, in which case neither of your solutions are how you should do that

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use the WP filesystem API if you are trying to access directories to which the web server has full access. It is needed mainly only when you want to write to directories which have limited access like the plugin directory. From that point of view the two snippets are the same.

What you are potentially doing wrong is trying to access a remote resource with file API. Your first snippet will fail on some hosts and I am totally not sure if the WP filesystem API will work.
A more robust way is to use the wordpress HTTP to get the content of the file with `wp_remote_get` and save it to the uploads folders.

... last thing don't do copyright infringements, too many people payed too much for such things.